# Stop function from running after element is clicked

Tags: jquery, function

I want to stop a function from running after a certain element is clicked.

This element comes in on scroll but if you click the cross I don't want it to come back when you scroll... how can I do this? It keeps on returning:

```
// Pilot green bar hide on opening page
jQuery(".try-pula").hide("fast");

// Show on scroll 700
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
if(height  > 700) {
        jQuery(".try-pula").show("fade");
    }
});

// close after x is clicked
jQuery( "#cross" ).click(function() {
  jQuery(".try-pula").hide();
});
```

Comment: Try to change `.hide();` to `.remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new variable. Set it to false on start.

```
var crossClicked = false;
```

Then, in your scroll function, check for this var, so it only executes while it is false.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if((height  > 700) && (crossClicked == false)) {
            jQuery(".try-pula").show("fade");
    }
});
```

Now, on cross click, set it to true:

```
jQuery( "#cross" ).click(function() {
  crossClicked = true;
  jQuery(".try-pula").hide();
});
```